# VPN - PPTPd server setup under Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, fedora-14

I've been using Debian as my main server for a while, and have pptpd (PoPToP) allowing me to connect my iOS devices and Windows laptop to my home network.

I have switched to Fedora 14 as a learning exercise but can't find an equivalent VPN server package to pptpd.  The pptp client is installed in Fedora, but the PPTP server is not available, the [poptop project](http://poptop.sourceforge.net/) hasn't been updated since 2009 and [poptop.org](http://poptop.org) is unavailable, leaving me to presume that the project is dead.

What should I use instead to setup a VPN host on Fedora Linux to allow my iOS and Windows clients to connect to the VPN?

Comment: If I remember correctly, PPTP is considered to be insecure.  Given that other secure options are available, it would not surprise me if the project has died.  PPTP client may be last longer to connect to legacy servers.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) is a good VPN software for both Windows and Linux, but I have no idea about iOS.

[L2TP](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/openswan-macosx.html) might be another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://blog.bradiceanu.net/2009/11/20/fedora-12-pptp-server/

or

http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/redhat-howto.phtml